# How to combine data frames with different (but sometimes overlapping) indexes over a period of time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a continuation of my [other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913979/how-to-combine-data-frames-of-different-sizes-and-overlapping-indexes-vertically/). Suppose I have a few data frames that are coming in with any random order (below, I'll mock those data frames).

```
# assume that df1, df2, df3 and df4 will come in any order
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'2016-01': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
'2016-02': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
'2016-03': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
'2016-04': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']},
index=['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'2017-01': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A5'],
'2017-02': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B5'],
'2017-03': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C5'],
'2017-04': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D5']},
index=['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N5'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'2016-01': ['A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9'],
'2016-02': ['B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9'],
'2016-03': ['C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9'],
'2016-04': ['D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9']},
index=['N6', 'N7', 'N8', 'N9'])

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'2017-01': ['A6', 'A7', 'A9', 'A10'],
'2017-02': ['B6', 'B7', 'B9', 'B10'],
'2017-03': ['C6', 'C7', 'C9', 'C10'],
'2017-04': ['D6', 'D7', 'D9', 'D10']},
index=['N6', 'N7', 'N9', 'N10'])

# this is the final data frame I'd like to build out of df1, df2, df3 and df4
desired_final_df = pd.DataFrame({
'2016-01': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', '', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', ''],
'2016-02': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', '', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', ''],
'2016-03': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', '', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', ''],
'2016-04': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', '', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', ''],
'2017-01': ['A1', 'A2',  'A3', '', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', '', 'A9', 'A10'],
'2017-02': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', '', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', '', 'B9', 'B10'],
'2017-03': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', '', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', '', 'C9', 'C10'],
'2017-04': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', '', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', '', 'D9', 'D10']},
index=['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5', 'N6', 'N7', 'N8', 'N9', 'N10'])
```

As explained in the code above, I'd like to build `desired_final_df` out of `df1`,`df2`,`df3` and`df4`. The best I can do for now is like this:

```
df12 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1, sort=True)
df34 = pd.concat([df3,df4],axis=1, sort=True)
desired_final_df = pd.concat([df12,df34],axis=0, sort=False)
```

But this approach requires me to know which one to append along `axis=1` vs. `axis=0`. **Is there a more pandas-like way of building consolidated data frame out of smaller chunks like above?** I'm thinking something along the lines of:

desired_final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in data_files: # we can replace [df1, df2, df3, df4] for demonstration purpose
    cur_df = pd.read_excel(f, index_col=0)
    if any(set(cur_df.index) & set(final_df.index)):
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, cur_df], axis=1, sort=False)
    else:
        final_df = final_df.append(cur_df)

Obviously, the above code is producing `desired_final_df`.

Any tip/suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: why do you think `pd.concat` is not `pandas-like`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, Probably a misunderstanding. I didn't say `pd.concat` is not pandas-like. I meant more like if there is a way to consolidate any incoming data frame of different time frame and indexes dynamically, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat` + `groupby` on `axis=1`

```
l=[df1,df2,df3,df4]
m=pd.concat(l,axis=1,sort=False)
m.groupby(m.columns,axis=1).first().fillna('') #ideally don't use the fillna
```

---

```
    2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 2016-04 2017-01 2017-02 2017-03 2017-04
N1       A1      B1      C1      D1      A1      B1      C1      D1
N2       A2      B2      C2      D2      A2      B2      C2      D2
N3       A3      B3      C3      D3      A3      B3      C3      D3
N4       A4      B4      C4      D4                                
N5                                       A5      B5      C5      D5
N6       A6      B6      C6      D6      A6      B6      C6      D6
N7       A7      B7      C7      D7      A7      B7      C7      D7
N8       A8      B8      C8      D8                                
N9       A9      B9      C9      D9      A9      B9      C9      D9
N10                                     A10     B10     C10     D10
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Maybe my question was a bit confusing. Your approach works if we can collect incoming data frames into a list like `l`. What if the data frames come in individually as in a `for cur_df [df1, df2, df3, df4]:`? Also, could you explain a bit more about why you recommended not to use `fillna` (performance reason?). Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind! I forgot that `group_by` doesn't change the `m` by calling, and I must assign it back to `m=m.groupby(....)`. Now I get it. :) But please let me know why you discourage using `fillna`. Thank you!

Comment: @user1330974 because it doesnt let you perform other operations involving na, `isna()` , `notna()` for instance, instead it requires you to something like `df==''` , anything involving string operation is slow, hence I dont recommend, but depends on your requirement , if the dataframes are coming in loop, you can save all in a list : `l=[]`; `for i in list_of_dataframes(): l.append(i)`

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains why running `fillna` is not optimal. :)